# gruntjs - Access Rev(ed) images from javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs

My Gruntfile.js includes a rev task on images, witch is fine :

```
rev: {
   dist: {
        files: {
            src: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

Now here's my javascript code in my app :

```
require(['app', 'jquery', 'jqueryBackstretch'], function (app, $) {
    'use strict';
    // use app here
    // console.log(app);
    // console.log('Running jQuery %s', $().jquery);
    $(function() {
        $('.stretch').backstretch(
            [
                'images/interieur.jpg',
                'images/10.jpg',
                'images/11b.jpg',
                'images/axo 02.jpg',
                'images/axo 03.jpg'
            ],
            {duration: 4000, fade: 'slow'}
        );
    });
});
```

How can I access my images files once the rev task has been run, and still be able to have access to those files in the 'grunt server' mode ?

Thanks.

Xavier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [`usemin`](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) ?
It's normally it's job to replace in your code the original filename with the minified/revved/.. version

`usemin` normally targets only CSS and HTML files but I believe editing the config should allow to parse js files as well.

I don't know `backstretch` but if this doesn't work, since you're users will download the images at some point, a hacky way around could be adding the images in your html with a  `class="special-class"` which would allow to select them with jQuery and also perform a `display:none;`. These images would have their sourced updated and you could then do it this way :

```
require(['app', 'jquery', 'jqueryBackstretch'], function (app, $) {
    'use strict';

    $(function() {
        var images = [];
        $('.special-class').each(function() { 
            images.push($(this).attr('src'));
        });
        $('.stretch').backstretch(
            images,
            {duration: 4000, fade: 'slow'}
        );
    });
});
```

That's far from perfect but if you can't get your way around with `usemin`, at least this should work.

Comment: I didn't find my answer using usemin. It just doesn't seem to be here for that. Your solution ended up working well, I just had to make sure the images weren't loaded twice. Thanks.